# How to create an element and move an existing element into it in native Javascript?

Tags: javascript

My goal is to create an element to serve as a placeholder of an existing element. For styling purposes I need to move the element right after another element (position: absolute is not a good solution) so I can set the position dynamic.

My problem is the markup is generated by javascript and the only option I have is to tweak it via javascript also. It is a third party widget that I need to override.

Current markup:

```
<li class="...">

  <a class="time" href="...." >
    <time pubdate="" class="...">...</time>
  </a>

  <div class="...">
    ...
  </div>

  <div class="...">
    ...
  </div>

  <div class="bottom-wrapper">
    <span class="stats-container">
      <span class="stats">
        <span class="likes">    
          ...
        </span>
        <span class="favorites">   
          ...
        </span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>
```

I want to move the `a.time` into a new span after `span.likes`.

Goal:

```
<li class="...">

  <div class="...">
    ...
  </div>

  <div class="...">
    ...
  </div>

  <div class="bottom-wrapper">
    <span class="stats-container">
      <span class="stats">
        <span class="likes">    
          ...
        </span>
        <span class="new-span">
          <a class="time" href="...." >
            <time pubdate="" class="...">...</time>
          </a>
        </span>
        <span class="favorites">   
          ...
        </span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</li>
```

I need to do it in native javascript (No Jquery) for some reason.

My code:

```
// Create a new, plain <span> element
var createElem = document.createElement('span');

// Get a reference to the element, before we want to insert the element
var containerElem = document.getElementsByClassName("likes");

// Get a reference to the parent element
var parentDiv = containerElem.parentNode;

// Insert the new element into the DOM after containerElem
parentDiv.insertBefore(createElem, containerElem.nextSibling);
```

However, the above code throw an error (please see below):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertBefore' of null 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertBefore' of undefined
```

Any idea how I can do this? Thanks

**EDIT: I have multiple LI as well. So I need to traverse all the LI in this script.**

Answer (score 4):

`containerElem` is an array :

```
var parentDiv = containerElem[0].parentNode;
```

Comment: I tried your correction above but I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined`

Comment: Then you do not have an element with class="likes". Could you tranfer your example to http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Or you are using some spooky browser, that does not support `getElementsByClassName()`. But that would throw a different error message.

Comment: thats what I suspect cause when I tried it in a test file the script executed fine.

Comment: @ninjascorner: You guess? What is there to guess about? Just check it!

Comment: Yes because when I did it plain html file `<script>function foo() { ... }</script><body>html here<script>foo()</script></body`. That works fine

Comment: try to move your script to bottom of the body tag or use <body onload="somefunction">... then put your script into this function

Comment: I cant touch the html since it is coming from external source.

Comment: window.addEventListener('load', function () {
/*here*/
});

Comment: @salexch: Do not use inline JavaScript and think about IE users when attaching events (`attachEvent`).

Comment: @salexch tried your last solution but there is no alert popping.

Answer (score 1):

1. **getElementsByClassName** is not a safe cross-browser DOM method. It will not work in IE 8 and below. If you need cross-browser support then using a getElementsByTagName('span') and checking the .className property would be a better option. Or better yet, just give the span an id and use getElementById (but I'm sure that thought must have occurred to you already).
2. Also, as @salexch rightly pointed out, if a DOM method returns a group of elements (HTMLCollection) as getElementsByClassName and getElementsByTagName do, then you must use indices (containerElem[0]) to access the individual elements within the collections.

"I tried your correction above but I get this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined"

This means the collection returned by your DOM method is empty. Are you sure that the span with class "likes" exists in the DOM at the time getElementsByClassName is called?

The rest looks fine. Hope you find your solution soon.